# Click on href and store data into input box

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

So I have a table with rows and columns that I loop through and an array which I split by spaces. What I am trying to do is if someone clicks parts[x] that information gets put into an input box.

```
var parts = data[j][i].split(' ');
tableData += '<td>';
for(x=0; x<parts.length; x++)
{
  tableData += '<a href="#">' +parts[x] + ' ' + '</a>';
}
tableData += '</td>';
```

For instance from below you can see the table that gets outputted now if someone was to press on Software I want Software to go to the top input box on the left which as you can tell already has Software in it for this example the input boxes name=a
[image]

Comment: Call function on click?

Comment: Yea I get that but how would i grab the contents of the click? Like how would I grab Beam or Software or Victor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a click listener to each  tag like this:

```
var parts = data[j][i].split(' ');
tableData += '<td>';
for(x=0; x<parts.length; x++)
{
  tableData += '<a href="#" onclick="clickedPart(this)">' +parts[x] + ' ' + '</a>';
}
tableData += '</td>';
```

Then define a handler outside of your tableData generation code like this:

```
function clickedPart(part){
    document.getElementById("input_box").value = part.innerHTML
}
```

Please note I assumed your input box has the id "input_box". You can change that to whatever you want, but I recommend giving it an ID instead of a name.